# AngularJS ui router $state.go not working

Tags: angularjs

I have a small search app using AngularJS and Elasticsearch and I'm trying to get UI Router's `$state.go()` to include my query parameters in the url and can not get it to work.... have no clue why?

In Chrome's address bar: `http://localhost:8000/app/search?q=searchTerms`

and it stays that way, even after searches are performed - when it should be: `http://localhost:8000/app/search?q=userTypedInput`

In my routes(states) I have

```
$stateProvider
      .state('search', {
        url: '/search',
        url: '/search?q',
        $stateParams: {q: 'searchTerms'},
        views: {
          '' : {templateUrl: 'search/search2.html',
                controller: 'SearchCtrl',
                contollerAs: 'search'}
          //add more views here when necessary
        }
      });
```

and in my controller I have

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('searchApp.search', [])
    .controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', '$state', '$stateParams', 'searchService', function($scope, $sce, $state, $stateParams,  searchService) {
        //Initialize
        //$scope.searchTerms = $stateParams || '';
    $scope.searchTerms = '';
        $scope.noResults = false;
        $scope.isSearching = false;

        //pagination
        //$scope.currentPage = 0;
        //$scope.itemsPerPage = 10;

        //results
      $scope.results = {
        queryTime: null,
        documentCount: null,
        documents: []
      };

$scope.search = function() {
    var searchTerms;
    $state.go('search', {q: 'searchTerms'});
    getResults();
  };

  var getResults = function() {
    $scope.isSearching = true;

    searchService.search($scope.searchTerms).then(function(response) {
... more code
```

What am I doing wrong? Results are displaying, I simply can not get the query parameters in the url with $state.go as I have it?

Comment: typo - you have two url fields in your state configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module("myApp", []).run(["$rootScope","$state","$stateParams", function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}]);

$stateProvider.state('search', {
    url: '/search?q',
    //don't specify $stateParams here
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'search/search2.html',
            controller: 'SearchCtrl',
            controllerAS: 'search'
        }
        //add more views here when necessary
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually have my routes/states in a routes module, should I put the .run code at the top of that module?

Comment: It would have been nice if you had added some text to explain how this answers the question